# How does Java use system proxy settings to access a website

Tags: java, proxy, vpn

I use a VPN client to access a website. My browers, like chrome, IE and firefox can all access the website. But java code, wget, curl cannot. Is there any setting for java to activate the function?

My VPN client is Jonus Pluse.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try run your java application with :
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080;
```

Or set proxy before you get access to the network using HTTP:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.example.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

From:
[Java Networking and Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

Comment: Hi, Jaskey. I did as you said. It shows "Connection timed out". For the proxy host is like "sslvpn.xxx.xxx.com", I guess I should use
    htttps.proxyHost
    https.proxyPort
instead. But it is still show errors "Connection reset".

Comment: @慧储 ,this should be a problem beyond the scope of proxy, check the answer and comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170980/connect-to-http-server-behind-vpn-with-java

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Typically, you would use system properties:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800 ....
```

Comment: Thank you, lafarer. As I said to Jaskey, it shows errors "Connection timed out."